# Robocopy: /move parameter not working correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I'm using a robocopy batch script to move files from one server to another,
but I need it to delete the files on the original server after it is done
(which should happen when you use /move).

The copying works fine, but the files and folders aren't deleted afterwards.
Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong?

Command:

```
robocopy "\\Srv04\data\logs" "F:\Logs" /move /S /minage:8
```

thanks,

Comment: What does robocopy say?

Comment: Seems I don't have permission to delete files on the share, only to create/access/copy them

Comment: ive tested it, it works. Thats a permission problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved: It was a permission problem

Answer (score 8):

Gotcha:- Please note that using ROBOCOPY with the /MOVE command other than permission problems won’t remove source directories and files if those items already exists at the target because they will be skipped.

You can get around this by quoting a new target destination.